# Efficient, concise approach to convert array dimension to list (and back) in R

Tags: arrays, r, performance, list, format

I convert between data formats a lot. I'm sure this is quite common. In particular, I switch between arrays and lists. I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing it right, or if I'm missing any schemas that would greatly improve quality of life. Below I'll give some examples of how to achieve desired results in a couple situations.

Begin with the following array:

```
dat <- array(1:60, c(5,4,3))
```

Then, convert one or more of the dimensions of that array to a list. For clarification and current approaches, see the following:

## 1 dimension, array to list

```
# Convert 1st dim
dat_list1 <- unlist(apply(dat, 1, list),F,F) # this is what I usually do

# Convert 1st dim, (alternative approach)
library(plyr) # I don't use this approach often b/c I try to go base if I can
dat_list1a <- alply(dat, 1) # points for being concise!

# minus points to alply for being slow (in this case)
> microbenchmark(unlist(apply(dat, 1, list),F,F), alply(dat, 1))
Unit: microseconds
                              expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 unlist(apply(dat, 1, list), F, F)   40.515   43.519   50.6531   50.4925   53.113   88.412   100
                     alply(dat, 1) 1479.418 1511.823 1684.5598 1595.4405 1842.693 2605.351   100
```

## 1 dimension, list to array

```
# Convert elements of list into new array dimension
# bonus points for converting to original array
dat_array1_0 <- simplify2array(dat_list1)
aperm.key1 <- sapply(dim(dat), function(x)which(dim(dat_array1_0)==x))
dat_array1 <- aperm(dat_array1_0,aperm.key1)
```

In general, these are the tasks I'm trying to accomplish, although sometimes it's in multiple dimensions or the lists are nested, or some such other complication. **So I'm asking if anyone has a "better" (concise, efficient) way of doing either of these things**, but bonus points if a suggested approach can handle other related scenarios too.

Comment: I would benchmark on a large dataset.  Also, based on the same data, `lst <- vector('list', dim(dat)[1]);for(i in seq_along(lst)) lst[[i]] <- dat[i,,]` seems to be faster